# How to display a Set<String> in a Swing JText Label.

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextcomponent

I have a Set words that I would like to display in the Swing JTextField/ or JTextArea.  Only these components only accept strings.  How do I convert this Set into a String?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Set to a String, and then pass it to the JTextField/JTextArea.

Simple using `toString()` on the set returns a String that looks like this: "[a, b, c, d]".

If you want to get rid of the brackets, you can call `toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could iterate the `Set` and build a `String` value of the elements, for example...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
for (String value : values) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        // For JTextArea
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        // For JTextField
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(sb);
}
String output = sb.toString();
```